# Integration of SvelteKit 1.0 and keycloak-js

Tags: typescript, keycloak, sveltekit

I setup a keycloak server in my localhost environment and I can get JWT token manually via postman and want to integrate auth in sveltekit.

I used [this](https://medium.com/keycloak/securing-a-svelte-app-golang-service-with-keycloak-e095774e5a03) as reference even if it is from Svelte and modified it to remove the errors, I managed to make it to partially work.

I have this code in my login route page and it successfully redirects the UI to my keycloak login:

```
<script lang="typescript">
  import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
  import type { KeycloakInitOptions } from "keycloak-js";
  // Keycloak
  let instance = {
    url: "http://localhost:8080",
    realm: "svelte-realm",
    clientId: "svelte-test",
  };
  let keycloak = new Keycloak(instance);  <---- error here.
  let initOptions: KeycloakInitOptions = { onLoad: "login-required" };
  keycloak
    .init(initOptions)
    .then(function (authenticated) {
      console.info("Authenticated");
    })
    .catch(function () {
      alert("failed to initialize");
    });
</script>
```

After logging in with the correct credentials I'm getting document is undefined error in keycloak.js file (from keycloak-js) specifically this line:

keycloak.js

```
...

var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
...
```

error message

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
  at new Keycloak(..../keycloak.js:718:20)
  at +page.svelte:... <--- line number of 'new Keycloak'
  at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
  at Object.default (root.svelte:41:38)
  at eval (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/components/layout.svelte:8:41)
  at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
  at root.svelte:40:37
  at $$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
  at Object.render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1884:26)
```

**UPDATE:**

I enclosed the whole keycloak code in onMount() and I'm no longer getting the document is undefined error but now I'm getting unauthorized (401) error in console:

```
http://domain/realms/my-realm/protocl/openid-connect/token
```

**UPDATE2:**

Sorry I totally forgot about this, I managed to fixed my 401 issue by setting client authentication to Off in my keycloack so it's accessible to the public.

Comment: any progress since your last update? I may soon give it a shot..

Answer (score 0):

The new error you are getting could be due to the port svelte/sveltekit is running on, the keycloack have settings you for what domain/url/port are allowed

Answer (score 0):

The error you've got is probably because you configured the client incorrect. I ran into the same problem and fixed it by setting the client public (Client authentication off). If not, Keycloak expects a Client Secret and you can't pass that with the keycloak-js adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the initialization of Keycloak within a onMount() that worked for me.